# Subject–Predicate Errors

Tags: grammar

The following quotes all seem to contain agreement errors between their subjects and predicates:

> A total of five youths were arrested in both incidents.

Shouldn't it be "A total . . . was"? The sense is plural overall, but the subject is the singular "total." The object of the preposition is "five youths." Nonetheless, the verb should be the singular "was," agreed?

> Early returns from rural areas indicated that support from the Communists remain strong.

Shouldn't it be ". . . support . . . remains strong"?

> A group of neighborhood volunteers are identifying these houses and forcing owners to fix them up or tear them down.

Shouldn't it be "A group . . . is"?

> The council's actions, concluding more than six hours of testimony on the matter, effectively nullifies a city hearings officer's decision.

Shouldn't it be "The council's actions . . . nullify"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP shows a clear understanding of subject-verb agreement. It appears to be a peeve.

Comment: Not off-topic because I was unsure whether I was correct or not. I presented my analysis and reasoning—and you confirmed as correct.

Comment: What appears to be ‘a peeve’?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question linked to by Andrew; but it is also noteworthy that the second and fourth examples are not examples of notional agreement: they’re just plain wrong. There is no notional plurality in #2, apart from the Communists (and they’re not what remains strong: the support is), nor a notional singular in #4, except for the council and the testimony (and they’re not what nullify: the actions are). Those two are presumably either typos, something written by a non-native speaker, or cases of someone inserting a parenthetical phrase and forgetting the original subject.

Answer (score 0):

You raise some good points. But the site has discussed this issue of subject-verb agreement many times in the past. A strong view, and the one by which I abide, is that with these collective-noun phrases, you need to do what **sounds** right.

For example, I would probably say, as would many people, 'A total of five youths were arrested...' It is not technically precise, but it sounds better (in my view).

But I might say 'A group of five people was stopped by the police...' I am not sure why one sounds singular and the other plural. perhaps it is just because 'a total of' does not indicate a clear unit of something.

Comment: We were all wrong on the first and third one. CMOS 16 says this: If a definite article (the) precedes, the mass noun controls, and typically a singular verb is used {the quantity of pizzas ordered this year has increased}. A "total" wasn't arrested; five youths were.

If an indefinite article (a or an) precedes, then the number of the noun in the prepositional phrase controls {a small percentage of the test takers have failed the exam}. A "total" wasn't arrested; five youths were arrested.

Comment: This has also been raised before, but it is "not technically precise" only if a priori, you assume a specific model of how agreement works, despite this model contradicting the actual available data. If you don't make that a priori assumption, then the technical precision problem goes away...

Comment: Could you put that in layman's terms and provide ancillary elucidation?

Comment: If a total of five youths were arrested, chances are they were arrested individually, at different times, in different places. If a group of five people is stopped by the police, there is only one stopping: the whole group is stopped as one, in one go. If you leave out the non-essential, you could say, “A group was stopped by the police”, but you would never say, “A total was arrested”.

Answer (score 0):

We were all wrong on the first and third one. CMOS 16 says this: If a definite article (the) precedes, the mass noun controls, and typically a singular verb is used {the quantity of pizzas ordered this year has increased}. A "total" wasn't arrested; five youths were.

If an indefinite article (a or an) precedes, then the number of the noun in the prepositional phrase controls {a small percentage of the test takers have failed the exam}. A "total" wasn't arrested; five youths were arrested. A "group" isn't identifying; the neighborhood volunteers are identifying. This is Chicago's rule.

Comment: +1 for providing info from a source (even if it is from a style guide). :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to decide cases like this—for the construction *a [collective noun] of [members]*—is to ask which noun is performing the action of the verb. Here I show how this works on your examples.

> A total of five youths were arrested in both incidents.

Were the *youths* arrested, or was the *total* arrested? The youths were arrested, so it should be *were*.

> Early returns from rural areas indicated that support from the Communists remain strong.

This isn't a construction *a [collective noun] of [members]*. The subject is *support*, so it should be *remains*.

> A group of neighborhood volunteers are identifying these houses and forcing owners to fix them up or tear them down.

Is the *group* identifying the houses, or are the *volunteers*? Both are, so either verb works.

> The council's actions, concluding more than six hours of testimony on the matter, effectively nullifies a city hearings officer's decision.

In this case, both the *council* and the *actions* nullify the decision. However possessives with apostrophes don't work like the construction *a [collective noun] of [members].* In this case you have to use the noun *actions*, so it should be *nullify*.